# In what sort of water do Squids spawn

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Do squids only spawn in normal water over level 41, or it can also spawn in flowing water over level 41?
Thank

Comment: http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Squid This may be useful. It states that "Squids only spawn between layers 45 and 63.", but does not comment on how flowing water affects their spawn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Squids will spawn in any body of water between Y-level 46 and sea level, though (obviously) they will go higher or lower as water permits. While they can spawn in any size body of water they'll, obviously, have a much higher spawn rate in larger pools.

If you're farming them, recommend a 15x15 pool ranging from Y-46 (bottom) to Y-64 (top) in depth. Gives you a decent pool to work with and covers the entire spawn range.

Comment: Thank you; in fact, I don't wanted to do a squid farm but i wanted to know if i could let the water flow in my grinder in order to stop the mob to spawn :)

Answer (score 2):

According to the Minecraft [Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Squid):

Squids can spawn in 1 or more blocks of water, any light level, spawning block must be between level 46 (inclusive) and sea level, and they can spawn in any biome.

In Pocket Edition, squid spawn only in ocean biomes. They also have a chance to spawn as babies.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they do. Not sure if in sideways flowing water, but in downwards flowing water thes surely do. I have a Guardian farm with downwards flowing water and Squids surely do spawn. Note that I last checked it at 1.7.10

Comment: Yeah, I perceived this when I did an error with the water flowing in my grinder (the water flowed down to the ground and when I was back there were squids peacefully swimming).